# Flex 3D Image gallery

Tags: apache-flex, 3d, gallery

I am looking for a free flex 3D image gallery, I have seen lot of free gallery but I am looking to get some thing like this

[Carousel with Scrollbar](http://example.procontent.net/Carousel/carousel_flex.html)

[Rotating Cylinder Image Gallery](http://www.flexdownloads.com/preview_source/104/)

[3D Cylindrical Photo Gallery in AS3 Flash](http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/cylinouter/)

the first one, i am not able to get any information.
 second  one is not free, but the 3rd one which is flash based, similar to second.  but not sure how to use/customize it in flex.

Answer (score 0):

http://papervision2.com/a-simple-papervision-carousel/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the link, but this carousel, does not have all features.  If you look at the link  "Carousel with Scrollbar"  It uses thumbnail  and upon clicking it loads the image.  There is lot of example like that also, but this one uses the blurred thumbnail, until the image is loaded. Also it shows the thumbnail in black and white and turns into color on mouse over.

Comment: this caurousel contain all basic functionalities. You can develop wat u need with this.

Comment: I am new to development and may be I am ready to buy component(first link), but unable to find the site, where I can get it